# Edit Document causes Word to crash

Tags: 2013, workflow, document, links

We have a workflow that creates a task containing a link to a document in SharePoint.
We seem to have an intermittent problem where a user will open their document from the link and upon clicking 'Edit Document' Word crashes with the error message "Microsoft Word has stopped working".
This only happens when opening the document through the link on the Task, as the 'Edit Document' button does not appear when opening the document direct.

I hope someone can assist with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: can you send here the property which you are using for creating link to the document in task? Have this user set properly permissions on this document? If you give here some screenshots it will be fine.

Comment: My custom task uses the 'Related Items' column which provides the link to the document.  All permissions are correct for the document.  Thanks.